# Azure website default page 'My Sites Title'

Tags: azure, web

I am probably being very dense here ... I'm built a very quick azure website. Published it, all looks good, but I can't for the life of me work out how to set the default page.

my site has default.aspx on the root. I've set that in the web.config as well, but when I hit the site I get a blank page served back with 'My Sites Title' and not very much in the source.

It's the page that was created before I pushed anything up, but I can't work out how to remove it.

Any clues?

thanks
Gerry

Answer (score 0):

ok found the answer to this so I thought i'd update.

There was a file in the root called Default.cshtml. Changing the default file settings in the azure websites control panel, or in the web config did not change this file being served as the default. Maybe I missed some instructions somewhere on how to get rid of it.

Anyway, my solution was to create an FTP user via the azure control panel, log in and delete it. Now my default.aspx page works.